# Rails module scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

Given the following controller structure:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActiveController::Base; end

# pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController; end

# admin/application_controller.rb
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController; end
end

# admin/pages_controller.rb
module Admin
  class PagesController < ApplicationController; end
end
```

One would expect `Admin::PagesController` to inherit from `Admin::ApplicationController` and it does. But I have noticed that sometimes it inherits from `::ApplicationController`.

So I decided not to risk it and changed declaration of all controllers in `/admin` to specifically target `Admin::ApplicationController`

```
# admin/pages_controller.rb
module Admin
  class PagesController < Admin::ApplicationController; end
end
```

Okay that works, but from what I know it was correct in the first place. Why Rails inherits from a wrong controller sometimes?

`Admin::PagesController` *sometimes* inherits from `ApplicationController` instead of `Admin::ApplicationController` despite both being in the same `module Admin`

Comment: I had experienced similar issue!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is rails' development mode code loading: in general code is loaded when you try to do something with a constant (eg subclass from it) and that constant doesn't exist. This results in `const_missing` being called and rails uses it this to try to load the class (for a detailed description see [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)).

If neither ApplicationController nor Admin::ApplicationController exist then when you access your admin pages controller ruby will hit that const_missing and try to load admin/application_controller.rb

However if ApplicationController is already loaded then ruby won't fire `const_missing` since it perfectly legal for a class in the admin module to inherit from something at the toplevel.

The solution as you say is to make explicit what you are inheriting from. Personally in my own apps I use `Admin::BaseController` as the base class.

Comment: Would it behave the same way in production?

Comment: @Nick In production everything is loaded upfront so I would hope not but I suppose that if the files were loaded in a certain order it could still happen - I don't know if rails tries to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`require_dependency`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#require-dependency) to point Rails to the correct file:

```
# admin/application_controller.rb

require_dependency 'admin/application_controller'

module Admin
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess in that case it is better to use a unique name like `AdminController` or explicitly state scope like `Admin::ApplicationController`